# Xor using bitwise operations

Tags: python-3.x, logic, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

Say I have a fn taking two ints A,B

Let binary rep of A be a0,a1,a2....an, and that of B be b0,b1,b2...bn .

I wish to return this ((a0 * b0) ^ (a1 * b1) ^ ..... ^ (an * bn)).

But the challenge is to achieve this without bit conversions i.e. using integers. How can I achieve this?

PS: I know A & B gives me a number. When this number is converted to binary and its elements are xorred amongst each other, I would get my answer. But I do not wish to convert the anded result to binary using bin() for faster computation.

```
    def find( int A,int B):

      multiply= A & B

      list= bin(multiply)[2:] #(this step I wish to avoid cuz the product can be super large and the binary string is long)

      list = [int(d) for d in list]
    
      innerprod = (reduce(lambda i, j: int(i) ^ int(j), list))

      return innerprod
```

Comment: Show your current implementation. It's not clear to me what you're doing or that you understand how the `^` operator works.

Comment: Noted. I added my code.

Comment: That's not quite python code...

Answer (score 2):

First bitwise "and" (`&`) the numbers to get a number whose bits are the bits of the input numbers, multiplied respectively.

You can use [Kernighan's algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/) to count the number of bits that are set to 1 (see link for description), in this number.

Then, mod 2 the result, because XOR is just flipping the result every time a bit set to 1 is encountered (so, an even number of 1's XOR'd together is 0, and an odd number will be 1).

Example:

- 7 is '111' and 5 is '101'
- 7 & 5 is '101' (bitwise "and" operation)
- Two bits in '101' are set to 1 (so `count_set_bits` returns 2)
- 2 modulo 2 is 0.
- (1 * 1) ^ (1 * 0) ^ (1 * 1) is 0

```
def count_set_bits(n):
    count = 0
    while n:
        n &= (n-1)
        count += 1
    return count

def compute_answer(a, b):
    return count_set_bits(a & b) % 2

print(compute_answer(7, 5))   # 0
print(compute_answer(37, 3))  # 1
```

Comment: Very nicely seen. You can also count the bits with `while n:;   count += n & 1;    n >>= 1`. Not sure which is faster. Also, python 3.10 will give integers a built-in `bit_length` method.

Comment: Thank You Elinda for understanding the problem( without me providing code) and providing such a bang-on answer!  tysm!

Comment: @MadPhysicist Kernighan’s Algorithm is faster. For example, if the input is 32 ('100000') then only one iteration of the loop executes (count is incremented one time) -- this is because all of the bits right of the least significant "1" in n, are flipped in n-1 -- therefore, in `n & (n-1)`, those rightmost bits would end up as "0", and all you need to do is count the number of times this happens before there's nothing left. This is in contrast to inspecting every bit, by shifting each time by 1 (`n >>= 1`)

Comment: @ELinda. Good call. I didn't think it through